# Regular expression select all digits after prefix with minimum and maxium number of digits and skipping non numric characters (max 4)

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression which selects a number after a key word.
Sample data:

- yyyuiy Contract \ 12345678
- hjdhd contract : 87654321 Payed
- somedata contract87654321T
- Error data contract:1234567899Error --> this has too many digits

The common keyword is "Contract", after this keyword, 0 to 4 possible non numeric characters. Then the number of the contract which is Always between 7 or 8 numbers. When there are more digits, its should not be selected.
I started with (?<=Contract)(.*)([0-9]+)
which selects to much. I only need the number and only when it has 7 or 8 digits.

If you have a sollution, can you also please explain how, so I can learn from it.

the result should be

- 12345678
- 87654321
- 87654321

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: [`(?<=contract)\D*(\d{7,8})(?=\D)`](https://regex101.com/r/0Bexm2/1)

Comment: Language is dot net. Im going to try to use them

Comment: Then simply use [`(?i)(?<=contract\D*)\d{7,8}(?=\D)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%28%3f%3c%3dcontract%5cD*%29%5cd%7b7%2c8%7d%28%3f%3d%5cD%29&i=yyyuiy+Contract+%5c+12345678%0d%0ahjdhd+contract+%3a+87654321+Payed%0d%0asomedata+contract87654321T%0d%0aError+data+contract%3a1234567899Error+--%3e+this+has+too+many+digits)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) to specify the number of digits and non digits and use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check that after 7 or 8 digits there are no more digits following.

To match all the variations of contract you could make the match case insensitive or match contract like `[Cc]ontract`

```
(?<=\b[Cc]ontract)\D{0,4}([0-9]{7,8})(?!\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IIVQ04/1)

That will match

- `(?<=\b[Cc]ontract)` Positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left is Contract or contract (If you don't want to use a lookbehind, you could also match it instead `\b[Cc]ontract`)
- `\D{0,4}` Match 0-4 times not a digit
- `([0-9]{7,8})` Capture in a group a digit 7-8 times
- `(?!\d)` Negative lookahead to assert what follows is not a digit

.NET supports infinite lookbehind. In that case you could get the match using:

```
(?<=\b[Cc]ontract\D{0,4})[0-9]{7,8}(?!\d)
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%5bCc%5dontract%5cD%7b0%2c4%7d%29%5b0-9%5d%7b7%2c8%7d%28%3f!%5cd%29&i=yyyuiy+Contract+%5c+12345678%0d%0ahjdhd+contract+%3a+87654321+Payed%0d%0asomedata+contract87654321T%0d%0aError+data+contract%3a1234567899Error+--%3e+this+has+too+many+digits)

Comment: Thanks, this is the best sollution. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex,

```
(?i)contract[^\d]{0,4}(\d{7,8})(?!\d)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - Enables case insensitive match as somewhere you have `Contract` and other `contract`
- `contract` - literally matches this text
- `[^\d]{0,4}` - Matches any character 0 to 4 times except a digit
- `(\d{7,8})` - Matches a digit of length 7 to 8
- `(?!\d)` - Rejects the match if there is a digit ahead

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DBOXlb/1)**

Comment: Thanks for the replys. and more for the explenations. 
This helped

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript: `/contract(?!(\d{0-4}))(\d{7,8})(?!(\d))/i`

"contract" followed by any 0 to 4 characters which are not numeric (`(?!(\d{0-4}))` means string with length between 0 and 4 which does not contain digits) until a sequence of 7 or 8 digits is found (`(\d{7,8})`) where the next symbol is not a digit (`(?!(\d))`). `i` flag means that the regex is case insensitive.

After I've answered I've seen that the question is .net related. In c# you can use the same pattern (except the `i` at the end) and pass `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
\b[cC]ontract\D{0,4}(\d{7,8})(?:\D|$)
```

[Demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/qML)